# Transformation of space at almost the speed of light from different observers

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I hear this a lot in documentary movies, where they claim that if you would be able to travel through space near the speed of light, then things would seem squished, the Earth would seem like a 70 meter thin disk. But from the point of view of an observer on the Earth would I be rather streched or also squished?

Comment: also squished, it is symmetric

Comment: This explains it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction be sure to read the opening paragraph and the symmetry section.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you will appear stretched or squished to an earth observer depends entirely on your history.

1. If you took off from earth, and if (according to earth clocks) the front of your ship started moving forward before the back did, then you will appear stretched (relative to your original length).
2. If (according to earth clocks) the back of your ship started moving forward before the front did, then you will appear squished.
3. If (according to earth clocks) the front and back of your ship started moving forward at the same time, then you will appear neither stretched nor squished.
4. If (according to the clocks on your moving ship) the front and back of your ship started moving at the same time, then you will see yourself as squished relative to your original length, and the earth observer will see you as squished even further.  (This is a special case of scenario 2.)

The asymmetry between you and the earth comes from the presumption that the earth does not accelerate; both ends of the earth are always stationary in its own frame, so we don't get to ask which side started moving first in that frame.